# Call REST service url in Java with DOMAIN(+ username+password) Authentication

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jersey-client

I am trying to get Response from a REST service URL, 
nut getting Error :
401 : Invalid username or password.

I am able to hit this URL in browser and get response with the provided credentials , 
as well as in SoapUI tool.
I am providing the Domain value in the Authentication section while hitting the URL from SoapUI, without which I am getting Authentication error.

But from java I am unable to get the response.

If anyone can please help

public class Test_Rest_WS {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost","omaproxy.1dc.com");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();


    //clientConfig.getFeatures().put( JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);

    Client client = Client.create(clientConfig); 


        final HTTPBasicAuthFilter authFilter = new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("mysuer", "mypassword");
        client.addFilter(authFilter);
        client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());



    WebResource webResource = client
            .resource("https://myurl");


      ClientResponse resp = webResource.accept("application/json")
      .type("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);

    if(resp.getStatus() != 200){
        System.err.println("Unable to connect to the server");
    }
    String output = resp.getEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println("response: "+output);
}
```

}

Getting this error with the above code :
401 : Invalid username or password

Expected output : The response xml.

Comment: Try to make a connection without the proxy. If a direct connection works the proxy might be messing up your authentication request.

Comment: Yes tried without proxy as well, still the same error. I guess it has something to do with the domain value, if there's a way we can pass the domain value to the authentication , it might work, I am trying the same, please let know if there's anything such you people are aware of.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi vikram,**

```
  check your username it may be wrong like myuser
```

Comment: I tried numerous times with the id/password , thats not the issue, I am quite sure.